# Where is the hypothesis 'F is an algebraically closed field' being used in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

The following is an exercise from Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra.

[image]

The lemma that I have used is this :

[image]

My attempt:

[image]

Is my solution correct and where is the hypothesis 'F is an algebraically closed field' being used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $c$ in Lemma is called $t$ in the Exercise.

In the proof "$\Rightarrow$" you **cannot assume** (what you implicitly do) that $c=f(t)$ unless the existence of $t$ is established.

Example: $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)=x^2$ and
$$
T=\left[\matrix{0 & 1\\2 & 0}\right].
$$
Then $f(T)=2I$ has the eigenvalue $2\in F$, but $T$ has no eigenvalues, so the implications in this direction fails.

Comment: ok so for the forward implication I showed that f(c)=c but it remains to prove that c is a characteristic value of T.Right? How to do that?

Comment: It is different $c$. You need to show that (a) $f(t)$ is an eigenvalue, and (b) all eigenvalues are of the form $f(t)$ for some $t\in\sigma(T)$. The (a) part is easy. The (b) part is trickier. Here you may need more knowledge about the geometry of $T$, e.g. Jordan form decomposition (possible for algebraically closed fields). It is probably the easiest. Alternatively, use the first order factorization of $f$ and do some $T$ calculus.

Comment: The general version of the result is known as the Spectral Mapping Theorem (look, for example, [here (pdf download)](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFQQFjAFahUKEwiKlLWryIDJAhXJiSwKHfqGCZ0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780817683276-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1338305-p174305860&usg=AFQjCNF0qHSWWWK8EeWKZfk_rWd1HpzlrA&sig2=rP1i2xpSBt6NVS-YgtqMCw&bvm=bv.106923889,d.bGQ), Th.2.7, p.35, for quite a simple proof)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Jordan Decomposition actually upper triangulation does the job.Here is a sketch:

By fixing a Basis for $V$ of course  we can assume that $T$ is a square matrix.By some theorem of Linear Algebra we can find a matrix $P$,with det($A$) non zero  such that $PTP^{-1}$ is an upper triangular matrix.Since $Pf(T)P^{-1}=f(PTP^{-1}$),hence $Pf(T)P^{-1}$ is also an upper triangular matrix.Now look at the diagonal element of $f(PTP^{-1})$,and hence we are done.

Comment: It is worth to point out that one also needs the field to be algebraically closed in order to get Schur triangularization.

Comment: Dear @A.G. thank you for pointing out.Best Regards,